# Not expected behaviour from search result objects in table view sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` with sections. Each `core data object` is shown under the expected section. To test the app, I have added 3 objects.

```
1. item 2(overdue)-> OVERDUE section
2. item 1(today)-> TODAY section
3. item 3(upcoming)->UPCOMING section.
```

I have also implemented a `search bar`, which is filtering the objects by the attribute todoName (only needs to match 3 characters).
This is a screenshot from the app in its first view:
[image]

If I introduce a search string into the search bar controller, the result objects are shown repeated and under all sections. Please see an example below, after searching for 'day'
[image]

This are my questions:

**1.** I would need that the result objects may appear under its previous section or under no section, but no under all sections.

**2.** The result objects have lost the right > sign and don't provide any action when tapping on them.

Any advice or help is welcome.
Here is my code so far:

```
#import "ToDoItemsTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoSubItemsTableViewController.h"

@interface ToDoItemsTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ToDoItemsTableViewController
@synthesize searchResults;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //navigation bar background image
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar

     setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]

     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;



    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        abort();
    }
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.searchResults = nil;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addToDoItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;
        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItem.todoDueDate = [NSDate date];
        addToDoItemViewController.addToDoItem = addToDoItem;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toToDoSubItems"]){

        ToDoSubItemsTableViewController *todoSubItemsTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ToDoItem *selectedToDoItem = (ToDoItem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        todoSubItemsTableViewController.selectedToDoItem = selectedToDoItem;



    }




}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = nil;



    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        toDoItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.todoName;



        NSDate *fechaToDO = toDoItem.todoDueDate;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
        NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



        cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;

    }
    else
    {


    ToDoItem *todoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = todoItem.todoName;



    NSDate *fechaToDO = todoItem.todoDueDate;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
    NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (section == 0) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else if (section == 1) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }


    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return vHeader;
}
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{




    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *sectionname = [theSection name];

    if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"0"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"O V E R D U E   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"1"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T O D A Y   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                           numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"2"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"U P C O M I N G   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }




    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count]>0){
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }

}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoDueDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Delegates

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{

            ToDoItem *changeToDoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = changeToDoItem.todoName;
            NSDate *fechaToDO = changeToDoItem.todoDueDate;

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
            NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }


}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}





/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }

    }
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        ToDoItem * item = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* name = item.todoName;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [name isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

---

I have changed the commitEditingStyle as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
     else   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
            ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]){
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            }





    }
    }
```

But at trying to delete a search result object, the app shows following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Please, check my changed method to detect where is the issue, thank you...

---

Here the complete exception, perhaps it helps you to detect the issue:

```
[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89be750
2014-01-16 22:54:08.530 To-Do Pro Light[2319:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89be750'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aab5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b48903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9b90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9b4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   To-Do Pro Light                     0x00004eda -[ToDoItemsTableViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 298
    6   UIKit                               0x0068cba3 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 107
    7   UIKit                               0x0080c695 -[UITableViewCell _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 70
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01840874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x0059e0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x0059e04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x006960c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x00696484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x00695733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x00910c7f _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    15  UIKit                               0x005db19a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    16  UIKit                               0x005dc0ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    17  UIKit                               0x005afe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x0059a18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3483f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01a341cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01a5129e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a50ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a508db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x038bc9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x038bc809 GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x0059cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  To-Do Pro Light                     0x00007d2d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x020e7725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
       return 1;
    }
    else
    { 
       return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
    }
}
```

Edit for your second question about the crash.

Change the `commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
     {
         [self.searchResults removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     }
     else
     {
         if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
         {
             // Delete the row from the data source
             NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
             ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
             [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


              NSError *error = nil;
              if (![context save:&error])
              {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if I update my code with your proposal, the result object appears only once, thats  nice, but the app shows it under the OVERDUE section (the search result object was from UPCOMING section). And also the > sign doesn't appear and the row actions (like Delete) show a weird behaviour.

Comment: @mvasco: you need to use the same if condition in `viewForHeaderInSection` and `titleForHeaderInSection`

Comment: which if condition?, both methods are completely different.

Comment: @mvasco: you need to check using `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` and return appropriate view and title from those methods. Also you can use `cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;` in the cellForRowAtIndexPath for setting the > arrow

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer including both methods with your proposal? I guess I am not implementing your proposal in the right way, then I am getting some warnings and errors.

Comment: OK, I have already made possible that the result objects appear under a new section called SEARCH RESULTS, the > arrow do also appear, but no action is executed when selected  a result object row, it should open a new view controller

Comment: @mvasco: sorry, i was offline. You need to implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and in this method you need to open the new view controller.

Comment: In my code, after tapping on the selected row, a new VC is open, it is made by a prepareForsegue method, could I use this segue method to differentiate when a normal row is selected and when a search result row is selected?

Comment: @mvasco: I think no, because the `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` is dynamically created. It won't use your tableview designed in the storyboard.

Comment: OK, I will try implementing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: And now the last question, the normal rows accept the commitEditingStyle method and I can delete the row swiping to the left and then tapping the DELETE button that appears. The row dissapears and the tableview reloads. But with the search results objects the behaviour is different, I swipe to the left, the DELETE button appears, but if i tap on it, the row stays as swiped to the left, the table view is not reloaded, I have to tap the cancel button to go back to the original table view, and the search result deleted item is also deleted...

Comment: @mvasco: Same if condition issue :) Now put it on `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and for searchDisplayTable the deleting can't be done like this. You need to call the `tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: I will need your help here, please put such a method example for the result objects...

Comment: @mvasco: do like: `// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];}}`

Comment: Sorry for being so inexpert, but there are then two commitEditingStyle methods, one for the normal rows and one for the search result objects?

Comment: @mvasco: no you need to put the existing current code in the else block of above written method

Comment: thank you for your time and patience, I have edited my question to include the method as you told me, but I guess I have done something wrong then the app throws an exception, please check it and change it as you consider to be done. Thank you again.

Comment: thank you, I have change my code for your proposal, but now there is another exception. I have included it in my question.

Comment: @mvasco: it is because the `searchResults` is NSArray change it's type to NSMutableArray